# Running selenium tests on an MSBuild build server

Tags: testing, msbuild, mstest

Our department uses Visual Studio 2008 Team System, and we have a build server that integrates with our TFS source control server. It pulls the source code, builds the solution and runs the unit tests, just as we might do from within VS, and emails a report. The build server is setup using MSBuild and MSTest as the primary tools. All very sweet.

On our development machines we also run a set of selenium unit tests, and I want to include this in the test suite on the build server. I have been told that 'this is not possible using MSBuild/MSTest', but I am at a loss to understand why.

Does any one have experience of running selenium tests (they are just conventional test methods written in C#) who might be able to advise me on whether this is possible and what the gotchas are? Thinking about it, apart from giving the browser access to the desktop when the server is not logged in, once MSBuild has handed off a test list to MSTest it's exactly the same process as on our develop machines.

TIA

Comment: I have used MSTest but ended up converting to NUnit mainly for pricing, ease of use and flexibility. That said, you are right, MSTest should work perfectly fine with it. Can you run the tests manually, using mstest in a command line, on the CI server? FWIW, we used Selenium with MSTest with TeamCity - so I'd be shocked to learn it won't work with this.

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging input.

Comment: Apperrantly, from some entry on the WideWeb, you cant use msTest v2 in conjunction with selenium drivers and TFS. It gives off odd errors as he said. And I totally Agree. I've been fiddling with this for two weeks now, after I upgraded to MSTest v2.
To me, whole point of having unittests is using a build server for this - I am baffled that this does not have higher priority at MS.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 3 years on, but someone might drop in on this post and not see an answer. This is possible todo.

In a similar fashion how you'd run unit test, in the build definition using default template you need to specify the name of the UnitTest DLL and ensure Run Unit Test is not disabled. Also ensure that the build is building your Automated UI Test solution.

Simples.